# MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock fetch returns faulted objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I am currently developing an iOS application that is heavily dependant on CoreData and persisting information constantly.

With the help of MagicalRecord, i've set up background saving using the saveInBackgroundWithBlock function.

The problem that I am having is that anything that is fetched within this block always returns faulted objects, even when I set the NSFetchRequest to "setReturnsObjectsAsFaults: NO".

I've run the same tests by fetching from the main thread using "MR_defaultContext" and these objects also return as faults.

The **only** way to not have these objects return as faulted objects is to use the "MR_rootSavingContext" to fetch objects from the store.

The weird thing about this is that I am setting the "setReturnsObjectsAsFaults: NO" and the objects are still returned as faulted objects.

The reason I need them to be un-faulted is that I know exactly what data needs to be updated, and firing faults on every object is a huge performance hit, whereas batching these faults will be much faster.

Some example code as to how I am setting up the fetch request is shown below:

```
    [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

        UserData *newUser = [UserData MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"index" withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:currentUserIndex] inContext:localContext];

        NSFetchRequest *documentsRequest = [DocumentData MR_requestAllWhere:@"user" isEqualTo:newUser inContext:localContext];

        [documentsRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

        NSArray *fetchedDocuments = [localContext executeFetchRequest:documentsRequest error:nil];


// Fetched data is manipulated here, but the above fetchedDocuments are all faulted, and as a result really slow to update here


}     completion:^{

        NSLog(@"Finished saving documents");

    }
     ];
```

**Update:**

[Here is a link to a sample project outlining the problem.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/79flcgkdang1y7u/CoreDataProblems.zip)